# In elasticsearch finding documents which meet a specific criteria for the latest for each group

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, bucket

I am trying to create a query in elasticsearch, which is able to retrieve the documents for each group, which is the latest document within each group and meet a specific criteria. But I have not been able to solve this one.

Say following documents are indexed in myindex in elasticsearch:

```
POST /myindex/_bulk
{ "index":{} }
{ "objid": 1, "ident":"group1","version":1, "chdate": 1, "field1" : 1}
{ "index":{} }
{ "objid": 2, "ident":"group1","version":2, "chdate": 2, "field1" : 0}
{ "index":{} }
{ "objid": 3, "ident":"group1","version":2, "chdate": 3, "field1" : 1}
{ "index":{} }
{ "objid": 4, "ident":"group1","version":2, "chdate": 4, "field1" : 0}
{ "index":{} }
{ "objid": 5, "ident":"group1","version":3, "chdate": 1, "field1" : 0}
```

I would like to find all documents, which has field1 set to x if the document with the highest chdate, for each ident and version, which has field1 set to x.

In a case where x is 0 then the documents, which has objid 4 and 5 should be returned
In a case where x is 1 then the documents, which has objid 1 should be returned

I tried to make following query:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_ident": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "ident.keyword",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "by_version": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "version",
            "size": 10000
          },
          "aggs": {
            "by_latest": {
              "top_hits": {
                "sort": [{
                  "chdate": {
                    "order": "desc"
                  }
                }], 
                "size": 1
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I am unsure how I can add the criteria that field1 should be equal to x

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query for that.

Query explanation:
`Filter` for "field1" = 0 `group_by` **ident** and `group_by` **version** and get the first `top_hits` for **chdate**.

```
GET myindex/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "field1": {
              "value": "0"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "by_ident": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "ident.keyword",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "by_version": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "version",
            "size": 10000
          },
          "aggs": {
            "by_latest": {
              "top_hits": {
                "sort": [
                  {
                    "chdate": {
                      "order": "desc"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "size": 1
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however this will not work in the case that field1 is 1 as it will pick objid 1 and 3. It wrongfully picked 3 as 4 is the one with the highest chdate

Basically what is needed is filter after the top_hits